# Serialize/Deserialize nested POCO property without nesting in json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

Consider:

```
 public class Foo
 {
    public string FooName { get; set; } = "FooName";
    public Bar Bar { get; set; } = new Bar();
 }

public class Bar
{
    public string BarName { get; set; } = "BarName";
}
```

If we serialize Foo() the output is:

```
{"FooName":"FooName","Bar":{"BarName":"BarName"}}
```

I want:

```
{"FooName":"FooName", "BarName":"BarName" }
```

What is the cleanest way of achieving this?

Comment: You would need to write a custom converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a custom converter, for example, this is a quick and dirty example:

```
public class BarConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(Bar) == objectType;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((Bar)value).BarName);
        value.Dump();
    }
}
```

And then decorate your model like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string FooName { get; set; } = "FooName";

    [JsonConverter(typeof(BarConverter))]
    public Bar Bar { get; set; } = new Bar();
}
```